# CIVICRM plugin leads to database error

Tags: wordpress

When downloading civicrm it immediately shuts down the website due to error database

Any help is much appreciated and is something I have been struggling with for MONTHS to figure out.
This is the error my host says popped up:

https://paste.websitehostserver.net/text_2022-01-22_05-03-16_gDI32TmKk2
or
"[13-Jan-2022 04:51:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/greenp18/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 53
[16-Jan-2022 11:24:25 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[16-Jan-2022 11:37:57 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[16-Jan-2022 18:35:46 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[17-Jan-2022 00:30:54 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[17-Jan-2022 02:09:15 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[17-Jan-2022 02:59:56 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[18-Jan-2022 02:12:51 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[18-Jan-2022 19:27:59 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations
[21-Jan-2022 02:53:56 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%'' at line 1 for query SELECT post_id as variation_id, meta_key as attribute_key, meta_value as attribute_value FROM wp73nj_postmeta WHERE post_id IN () AND meta_key LIKE 'attribute\*%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/one-page-express/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/one-page-express/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_blocks, render_block, WP_Block->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractBlock->render_callback, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->render, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->get_products, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\BlockTypes\AbstractProductGrid->prime_product_variations"

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!  Those errors look to relate to WooCommerce, not CiviCRM.  What happens if you disable WooCommerce?

Comment: Those are definitely WooCommerce and not CiviCRM errors.  However, if you can definitively say that the site works with CiviCRM disabled, and not when it's enabled, then it's likely your host gave you the wrong errors - it's not uncommon.